# Formating Array of json objects into array of objects in C or Java

Tags: java, json, parsing, multidimensional-array

I have a JSON file with a structure that looks something like this:

```json
{
    "ASDAS": {
        "g": 100,
        "f": {
            "a": false,
            "b": 83,
            "c": 8728,
            "d": 84,
            "e": "2023-03-24T18:36:18.861Z"
        }
    },
    "WQEQW": {
        "g": 80.9,
        "f": {
            "a": false,
            "b": 344,
            "c": 742,
            "d": 326,
            "e": "2023-03-24T18:44:13.798Z"
        }
    }
}
```

However, the file is quite large and I wish to parse its data into an array of objects. In this new array, the first parameter of the structure would be something like a name. The issue I'm facing is that I'm struggling to parse the file correctly.

I tried modifing the file into something like this :

```json
{
    "objects": [{
        "ASDAS": {
            "g": 100,
            "f": {
                "a": false,
                "b": 83,
                "c": 8728,
                "d": 84,
                "e": "2023-03-24T18:36:18.861Z"
            }
        },
        "WQEQW": {
            "g": 80.9,
            "f": {
                "a": false,
                "b": 344,
                "c": 742,
                "d": 326,
                "e": "2023-03-24T18:44:13.798Z"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

So, it would be easier to parse the data into the objects. One of the final objects would be nice if it looked something like this:

```json
object(
  name=ASDAS,
  g=100,
  f(a=false, b=83, c=8728, d=84, e=2023-03-24T18:36:18.861Z)
);
```

(This would be inside an array with others.)

I would appreciate an answer in either C# or Java, but if you can provide a more generic solution (links for things like this), I would not be upset either!

Comment: The modified object is just enclosed in a parent object and wrapped in an array, do I see that correctly? Your "final objects" isn't valid JSON, so it is not exactly clear what you are after

Comment: Yes you did see that correctly .However  thats how the api i am using was designed feels like the "name" i wanted as a variable of the object has it own variable for every diferent object. 

I am sorry if i am not being clear. But this is kinda hard to explain since my first language ain t english.